# Remove users from shared Workbook if workbook opened more than 2 hours

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove users from shared Workbook if workbook opened more than 2 hours by that user.

The below code removes all users (except me). How do I adapt it to add condition to remove only users whom opened this work for more than 2 hours?

[image]

```
Sub Remove_Timed_Users_from_Shared_Workbook()
   
    Dim UsrList()
    UsrList = ThisWorkbook.UserStatus

    For i = UBound(UsrList, 1) To 1 Step -1
        If UsrList(i, 1) <> Application.UserName Then
            ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser i
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the 2nd argument of `UserStatus` for the timestamp, calculate how many seconds it has been since that timestamp, and then you can compare it to 2 hours with some math.

```
Sub Remove_Timed_Users_from_Shared_Workbook()
    Const TwoHours As Long = 60 * 60 * 2
    Dim Seconds As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim UsrList()
    UsrList = ThisWorkbook.UserStatus

    For i = UBound(UsrList, 1) To 1 Step -1
        If UsrList(i, 1) <> Application.UserName Then
         'If UsrList(i, 3) = 2 Then ' if it is shared/removable(?)
            Seconds = DateDiff("s", UsrList(i, 2), Now)
            If Seconds > TwoHours Then ThisWorkbook.RemoveUser i
         'End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Not sure it will let you actually remove the user tho. Please let us know if there is some restriction you are not able to get around. If the Shared/Exclusive matters, you can use the check on the lines I commented out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to test this since I'm not on a work network, but I think **[`ThisWorkbook.UserStatus(2)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.userstatus)** is what you're looking for.

> [[`Workbook.UserStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.userstatus)] returns a 1-based, two-dimensional array that provides information about each user who has the workbook open as a shared list.
>
> The first element of the second dimension is the name of the user, the second element is the **date and time when the user last opened the workbook**, and the third element is a number indicating the type of list (1 indicates exclusive, and 2 indicates shared).

However your plan seems dangerous. What happens if the user is in the middle of working on the workbook when the clock hits 2 hours?  Kick 'em out anyway, potentially losing unsaved changes?

Comment: @ashleedawg.There is another code to save the workbook and close automaticly after 1 hour and 45 minutes , but for some reasons (I think local network) these users not removed from list and after some time this list will be full of duplicate and redundant users , which leads to slow down and hanging for all others.